# Possible values for <w:outlineLvl> in Word OOXML

Tags: xml, ms-word, openxml

What are the possible values of `w:outlineLvl` node in Word OXML?
As when I am creating a normal word document the value ranges from 0-8 and its value is blank for outline level "Body Text".

But for a specific document the value is 9 is it a valid value?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see *ECMA-376, Office Open XML File Formats - Fundamentals and Markup Language Reference*, 4th Edition, page 233:

> ### 17.3.1.20 `outlineLvl` (Associated Outline Level)
>
> This element specifies the outline level which shall be associated
>   with the current paragraph in the document. The outline level
>   specifies an integer which defines the level of the associated text.
>   This level shall not affect the appearance of the text in the
>   document, but shall be used to calculate the TOC field (§17.16.5.68)
>   if the appropriate field switches have been set, and can be used by
>   consumers to provide additional application behavior.
>
> The outline level of text in the document (specified using the val
>   attribute) can be from 0 to 9, where 9 specifically indicates that
>   there is no outline level specifically applied to this paragraph.
>   If this element is omitted, then the outline level of the content is
>   assumed to be 9 (no level).

**So, `w:outlineLvl/@w:val` is an integer ranging from `0` to `9`, where `0` indicates the first outline level and `9` signifies no outline level.**